# Converting from fixed width columns to csv

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I have a fixed length text document that I would like to parse and output to a CSV file and add a header to the newly created document that is not in the raw data.  Below is the code I have for parsing based on column width.

```
import pandas as pd

path = '5010.txt'

col_specification =[(1, 12), (13, 18), (19, 26), (27, 31), (32, 39), (40, 47), (48, 57), (58, 62), (63, 67), (68, 72), (73, 77), (78, 78), (79, 83), (84, 84), (85, 86), (87, 92), 
(93, 97), (98, 98), (99, 103), (104, 104), (105, 106), (107, 112), (113, 120), (121, 128), (129, 129), (130, 131), (132, 134), (135, 139), (140, 155), (156, 171),(172, 187), (188, 203), 
(204, 213), (214, 221),]
data = pd.read_fwf(path, colspecs=col_specification)
```

How do I output `data` to a CSV file with a header?

Comment: What should the output look like? Should it be identical to `5010.txt` but with a header?

Comment: Pascal, the output should be either a space or comma delimitated txt or CSV. So not identical it would parse the raw data based on the fixed length criteria and output a csv or text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame's [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
data.to_csv("out_file.csv", header=["column1 title", "column2 title",...])
```

This will save the index (in effect, the row number) as the first column. To suppress this behaviour, pass the additional argument `index=False` to the method call.

Comment: the `data.to_csv("out_file.csv", index=False)` will create a CSV properly formated.  However when I try your header method the CSV is created but empty i.e no data or headers within the file.

Comment: This works for me. Does pandas throw an error when you try and save? Can you post the exact code that you are using to save the CSV file?

Comment: Your original suggestion works as you posted. I was incorrect I had a syntax error.